# Place element inside parent including its borders

Tags: css, pagination

I am struggling to create pretty pagination - I wanted to place anchors inside div so they would fill whole space with their borders but it looks like borders get out of parent, they do not stay inside and fill available space (as I thought they should). How can I deal with this behavior?

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 1200px;
  background: #e2f2fc;
  color: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 0;

  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25em;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  padding: .75em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 2rem;
  background: yellow;
}

.pagination>a {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my pagination page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <form>
        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" aria-describedby="example1_info">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th>Rendering engine</th>
              <th>Browser</th>
              <th>Platform(s)</th>
              <th>Engine version</th>
              <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Rendering engine</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Browser</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Platform(s)</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Engine version</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
            <tr class="even">
              <td class="  sorting_1">Gecko</td>
              <td class=" ">Mozilla 1.0</td>
              <td class=" ">Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
              <td class=" ">1</td>
              <td class=" ">A</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="counter">
            Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries
          </div>
          <div class="pagination">
            <a href="#">← Previous</a>
            <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
            <a href="#">2</a>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <a href="#">Next →</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the links are inline elements. Make them `inline-block` instead, and remove the `height` from `.bottom` (because that is currently too little to encompass those links with their full padding.)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 1200px;
  background: #e2f2fc;
  color: #333;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em 0;

  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .25em;
  text-align: left;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  padding: .75em;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: yellow;
}

.pagination>a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my pagination page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="box">
      <form>
        <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable" aria-describedby="example1_info">
          <thead>
            <tr role="row">
              <th>Rendering engine</th>
              <th>Browser</th>
              <th>Platform(s)</th>
              <th>Engine version</th>
              <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Rendering engine</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Browser</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Platform(s)</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Engine version</th>
              <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
            <tr class="even">
              <td class="  sorting_1">Gecko</td>
              <td class=" ">Mozilla 1.0</td>
              <td class=" ">Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
              <td class=" ">1</td>
              <td class=" ">A</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="counter">
            Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries
          </div>
          <div class="pagination">
            <a href="#">← Previous</a>
            <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
            <a href="#">2</a>
            <a href="#">3</a>
            <a href="#">Next →</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```